# Unity - move animated game object with rigidbody.velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an animated character , and I need move it forward

I add rigibody to my character , and mover class

when I disable animated controller it moves

my mover class

```
 using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class Mover : MonoBehaviour {


        public float speed;
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.forward * speed;

        }


    }
```

any suggestion how I can approach that

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find out the answer

just uncheck **Apply Root Motion**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Might want to put it in `Update()` so its not just called one time.

```
void Update () {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.forward * speed * Time.smoothDeltaTime;
}
```